# Compiling C++ code with Bazel fails due to "Argument list too long"

Tags: bazel

I have a huge project which consists of many libraries that are tied together (deps).

When compiling, Bazel creates the famous virtual includes and adds the corresponding -iquotes/-I for the compiler.

As this list is very big, the compiler fails with the error:

```
/my/path/to/the/toolchain/cc1': execv: Argument list too long
```

I did try to remove the limits on the stack and my current ARG_MAX is:

```
jbasila@fedora $ getconf ARG_MAX
4611686018427387903
```

A good way to make this work is probably by using the '@' param files. I know that it is in use for the linking but not for compiling.

Is there a way to make this work also for compiling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad news, we don't currently create param files for compile actions. You might be saved by https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/pull/3712 once it's merged in. Feel free to open a feature request for param files for compile actions.